# Volley Request Not Going

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm using Volley for authentication, but getting **Null pointer exception**. I tried to **DEBUG**, but couldn't find where it's passing null. My code is below

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = Const.URL_LOGIN + "?username=" + username.getText().toString() + "&password=" + password.getText().toString();


            //StringRequest requestString = new StringRequest(url, cre, errorListener)

            showProgressDialog();
            JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, 
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                       VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString());
                       hideProgressDialog();
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                       VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                       hideProgressDialog();
                   }
               });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj);
        }
    });
```

logcat:

```
08-20 11:07:02.382: W/dalvikvm(2172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419ae6f8) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172): Process: com.deliveryscience.track, PID: 2172 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):    java.lang.NullPointerException 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    com.deliveryscience.track.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)    
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    android.view.View.performClick(View.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)    
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java) 
08-20 11:07:02.382: E/AndroidRuntime(2172):     at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've edited it and added the code to my AppController class

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: `I tried to DEBUG` - or disinfestation ? you know, there is written `NPE at (blalbla.java:XXX)`

Comment: I use the Debugger @Selvin and traced it all and Sorry, I don't seem to understand you

Comment: Can you post full logcat?

Comment: Done @Dhruti posted with the code

Comment: oh here is the null MainActivity.java:79 ...

Comment: what's line MainActivity.java:79? There is something null

Comment: That's the name of the java file

Comment: and 79 is the line where is NPE

Comment: Is the login button instatiated?

Comment: login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);               @GeorgeD

Comment: @GeorgeD ... well NPE is inside the on click so it should be ... but i'm pretty sure that you are on right track ...  i'm pretty sure that the 79 line is `String url = Const.URL_LOGIN + "?username=" + username.getText().toString() + "&password=" + password.getText().toString()` ...

Comment: this is what's in line :79  AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req, tag_json_obj); @GeorgeD

Comment: it is pretty obvious: `AppController` is null or, if getInstance is a static member, AppController.getInstance() returns null ...

Comment: yes, it's a Static method

Comment: it seems that `AppController.getInstance()` returning a `null` value. double check there or add the code in `AppController` to your question.

Comment: Added my AppController code @Sirlate

Comment: Have you declared `AppController` in manifest so it gets instantiated as the `application`?

Comment: Ohw, I fee Like dying. I didn't think to that guy, I totally Forgot. That solved it @laalto Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you do not declar Application class name in your `manifext.xml` file.

do this:

```
<application
        android:name="AppController"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```